# plsql insert, update for existing id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to write a stored proc for the below requirement.

Desired output : TAX table

```
CATEGORY_ID TAX_PERCENTAGE  FROM_DATE   CREATE_DATE             TAX_ID  TO_DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1           10              4/1/2012    12/19/2013 8:54:20 PM   61      31-MAR-13
1           12.5            4/1/2013    12/19/2013 8:54:44 PM   62      31-dec-9998
```

When a new CATEGORY_ID say 1 with tax_percentage 10  for business year(from_date)  4/1/2012 is  inserted, then a default value should be placed in to_date column say 31-dec-9998. When i try to input the same cat_id  1 with diff set of values say tax_percentage 12.5, this time from_date 4/1/2013 then to_date value  should be (from_date-1) of cat_id 1,tax_percent 10 and my to_date value of 10,cat_id=1 should be updated with default date 31-dec-9998.something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SCOTT.Sp_SaveNewTaxPercentage
(
    iv_category_id number,
    iv_tax_percentage varchar2,
    iv_from_date varchar2,
    iv_to_date varchar2 default '12/31/9998' ,
    iv_created_date date,
    ov_err_code out nocopy varchar2,
    ov_err_msg out nocopy varchar2
)
is
    lv_category_id varchar2(25);
    LV_TO_DATE varchar2(25);
    lv_cat_id varchar2(12);

begin
    ov_err_code:=0;

    for J in ( SELECT CATEGORY_ID,FROM_DATE FROM TAX_P WHERE CATEGORY_ID =IV_CATEGORY_ID)
    loop

        SELECT to_date(iv_from_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') -1  INTO LV_TO_DATE FROM DUAL;
        lv_cat_id := J.CATEGORY_ID;

    end loop;

    update tax_p set TO_DATE=LV_TO_DATE where CATEGORY_ID =lv_cat_id;

    commit;

    IF lv_cat_id IS  NULL THEN 

        LV_TO_DATE := iv_to_Date; 
    END IF;

    insert into tax_p( TAX_ID , CATEGORY_ID  ,TAX_PERCENTAGE, FROM_DATE ,TO_DATE,CREATE_DATE)
    values(tax_seq.nextval,iv_category_id,iv_tax_percentage,iv_from_date,LV_TO_DATE,sysdate);

    select 'Successfully Saved' into ov_err_msg from dual;

    commit;
Exception 
when others then 
    rollback;
    ov_err_code:=1;
    ov_err_msg:='Error while saving'||SQLERRM;
end Sp_SaveNewTaxPercentage;
/

show errors;
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: i want to update the TO_DATE column of col 2 ie CATEGORY_ID 1 TAX_PERCENTAGE 12.5 with default date value at the same time i want to change the to_date column of col 1   ie CATEGORY_ID 1 TAX_PERCENTAGE 10 with col2's from_date -1

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to loop records to update the `to_date` field, just a single `UPDATE` statement will work for you.

```
BEGIN
     UPDATE tax_p
     SET    to_date = to_date(iv_from_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') -1
     WHERE  category_id = iv_category_id;

     INSERT INTO tax_p(tax_id, category_id, tax_percentage, from_date, to_date, create_date)
          VALUES(tax_seq.nextval, iv_category_id, iv_tax_percentage, iv_from_date, iv_to_date, SYSDATE);  

     COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN ...
     ...
END;
```